# how to integrate Telerik Reports with Application through VS Code

Tags: telerik-reporting

I want to generate the report using Telerik Reporting,
I install Telerik UI for.NET core
I want to generate reports through the web application in .NET Core

1. I want to know how to create reports through the application.
2. Which template do we need to use, to generate Telerik Reports
3. Do we need Telerik packages? Which one?

Search on Telerik Reports Documents,
I want correct way to solve this

Comment: The reports should largely be built through the telerik report tool. You should also add a report viewer to your application. Rptshell.aspx or something of that nature. Of you're starting with Telerik, you'll soon find that their forums are frequently your best resource. [Here is a link to a tutorial from Telerik on integrating their reports into your app](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/getting-started/first-steps-integrating)

Answer (score 2):

Creating complex reports can be quite the complex task, so the suggested approach is to use on of the three designer tools

- [Standalone report designer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/desktop-designers/standalone-report-designer/overview) - a standalone desktop application, which enables the whole feature set of Telerik Reporting for creating custom reports.
- [Web report designer](https://docs.telerik.com/reporting/designing-reports/report-designer-tools/web-report-designer/overview) - a web-based widget, which is suitable for adding report creation capabilities to a web application
- Visual Studio report designer - this one is yet to be implemented for .NET Core and .NET 6, it is currently only supported for .NET Framework Application. It is a designer that integrates with thee VS designer surface.

These articles provide detailed steps for starting with the selected approach.